# Selecting same id but different type

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have 2 inputs with the same id but different types:

```
<input id='aid' type='text' value='text value'>
<input id='aid' type='hidden' value='hidden value'>
```

I am trying to use

```
alert($(**INSERT SELECTOR HERE**).attr('value'));
```

to select and show the value "hidden value"

What selector can I use? '#aid:hidden' doesnt seem to work.

I attached a jsfiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/L8TtT/1/

Thanks

Comment: You cannot have two elements with the same ID.  You will get unreliable results if you do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('input[type=hidden]').attr('value');
```

Comment: thanks =) 

alert($('#aid[type=hidden]').attr('value')); selects by ID

Comment: This will select _every_ hidden input.

Comment: Yes it will. There's no additional information to give a better selector.

Answer (score 5):

You cannot have multiple elements with the same ID.

Use a class name instead:

```
<input class='aid' type='text' value='text value'>
<input class='aid' type='hidden' value='hidden value'>
```

You can then write `$('.aid:hidden')`